# Recovering lost geometry columns in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, upgrade, geometries

We have been running v10 of PostgreSQL with PostGIS 2.4. We are in the process of migrating to PostgreSQL 14 with PostGIS 3.2. There appeared to be an issue with pg_upgrade and the PostGIS version, so we upgraded PostGIS in v10 to 3.2 using

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;
SELECT postgis_extensions_upgrade();
```

Prior to running these statements I installed PostGIS 3.2 using stack builder; this is on a Windows server. The install and these statements did upgrade PostGIS to version 3.2, but now it appears that that all tables in the db have lost their geometry columns. How can this be and is there any way I can get these back without retreiving a backed up version of the db? I can see the geometry_columns view in the database, but it is now empty.

Comment: Are the columns actually gone *from the tables* (i.e. deleted) or are they present but *not defined* as any of the `GEOMETRY` types? There have been some major changes between versions, both in PostgreSQL and subsequently also PostGIS, in how the system registers and retrieves type specific modifiers (*type mods*). When updating major versions, the conversion steps my have not been executed, and rendered the system unable to infer the correct types.

Comment: @geozelot the columns are not present